# Method for computing the pressure drop across a bank of tubes

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, heat-transfer, heat-exchanger

I would like to determine the pressure drop of fluid in cross flow over a bank of tubes. (see figure 1).

[image: Horizontal cylinders represent tubes. Arrows parallel to the cylinders are labeled "internal flow of fluid through tube." Arrows perpendicular to tubes are labeled "fluid in cross flow over tube bank."]

Previously, I've used the correlation listed in "Fundamentals of Heat and Mass Transfer" by Incopera and DeWitt. However, this correlation requires looking up coefficients on a graph (see figure 2 - f is used to mean Eu/k by Incopera).

[image: A graph showing a variety of lines correlating f to Re at a variety of values of Pt, and another graph correlating chi to Pt/Pl at a variety of values of Re]

Now, I'd like calculate a pressure drops across a large number of tube banks in a computer program I'm running, so I need a correlation that's either just one equation or based on a lookup table. I tried using tables 1 and 2 from [the Thermopedia article on tube banks in crossflow](https://www.thermopedia.com/content/1211/). While this gives reasonable answers at some points, it also produces clearly incorrect answers at others. For example, for a square in-line bank, this correlation shows that Euler's number for b=2.0 exceeds Euler's number for b=1.5 as Re approaches 1e6, which doesn't line up with the graphs and also is obviously an incorrect answer (See figure 3, b=1.5 is in orange and b=2.0 is in green).

[image: Log/log graph showing a blue (b=1.25), orange (b=1.5), and green (b=2.0) line.]

Is there a correlation which I could use in my program which is more accurate than the one on Thermopedia?

Comment: So make a data table of x & y values then use vlookup() or interpolation to get the value of y for a given x based on the curve you want. Did this for many characteristics when i first got into excel. There is a program called DataThief which will take an image of a graph and give you x & y values...

Comment: Thank you for recommending DataThief - I think that is the right solution!

Comment: My favourite plot digitizer is the online [WebPlotDigitizer](https://apps.automeris.io/wpd/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I developed a solution to this problem and published it as a Python library called [tubebank](https://github.com/ellieLitwack/tubebank). You can install it using pip. I used the method proposed here by Solar Mike.

---

**Edit**
The comment made by Solar Mike, regarding the methodology to solve the problem.

*So make a data table of x & y values then use vlookup() or interpolation to get the value of y for a given x based on the curve you want. Did this for many characteristics when i first got into excel. There is a program called DataThief which will take an image of a graph and give you x & y values...*

Comment: For Python, there is a library [ht](https://ht.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) which should also support [pressure drop across bundle](https://ht.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ht.conv_tube_bank.html) (search for 'dP_Zukauskas').